# Passing a Dependency to Tab Bar View Controllers

Tags: swift, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to refactor an app to use dependency injection for the core data stack.

There's a great explanation here:
http://cleanswifter.com/dependency-injection-with-storyboards/

My problem is that in my app the view controllers linked by the uittabbarcontroller are embedded in navigation controllers, so this code:

```
  if let tab = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    for child in tab.viewControllers ?? [] {
      if let top = child as? PersistenceStackClient {
        top.set(stack: persistenceStack)
      }
    }
  }
```

doesn't ever see them. 
My instinct is that I need to change the `for child in` to something that references the child of the navigationcontroller, but all attempts have failed.

I'm thinking I need something along the lines of:

```
for child in tab.navigationController?.viewControllers
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I have solved this:

```
    if let tab = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        for child in tab.viewControllers ?? [] {
            for nav in child.childViewControllers {
                if let top = nav as? PersistenceStackClient {
                    top.setStack(stack: coreDataStack)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```